# Merge [google-admin-sdk] and [admin-sdk]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

**Problem**

We have two nearly identical (down to wiki wording) tags that represent the Google Admin SDK product (which is currently called G Suite Admin SDK):

1. [google-admin-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-admin-sdk) (1176 questions, tag wiki contains example APIs, created 7 years ago)
2. [admin-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/admin-sdk) (64 questions, no API examples, tag wiki nearly duplicates first, created 5 years ago)

Some of the questions [use both tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/admin-sdk+google-admin-sdk) (22 ATTOW) despite them being essentially the same tag.

**Proposal**

I propose we merge the tags into [google-admin-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-admin-sdk) and possibly do not synonymize [admin-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/admin-sdk) as it may be coined for general questions about admin SDK (that said, I am not adamant on the second part of the proposal).

**Optional proposal 1**

After the merge, the tag can be renamed to [gsuite-admin-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gsuite-admin-sdk) since this is how it is called in official documentation.

**Optional proposal 2**

> retagging of [firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase) + [admin-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/admin-sdk) to [firebase-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-admin) completed

I noticed that [admin-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/admin-sdk) is sometimes used as a ["lego brick" tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase+admin-sdk) with [firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase) to glue a "Firebase Admin SDK" tag, while the correct tag (naming of which transcends this discussion) is [firebase-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-admin) (see its tag [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/firebase-admin/info)), so we might need a *retag* as a preliminary action<sup>0</sup>.

**Tag graphs**

Below are 5-year [question activity graphs](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1261578/questions-posted-with-a-tag) for both tags.

[google-admin-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-admin-sdk) dancing around 15 "ok" questions per month:

[image: google-admin-sdk-5-year-graph]

[admin-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/admin-sdk) approximately 2 questions per month:

[image]

---

<sup>0</sup> Happy to do one myself if given the greenlight

Comment: Note for those who disagree: please participate in the discussion - the existence of two tags that serve one purpose is a bothering thing, and I haven't been able to find any previous discussion regarding the tags.

Comment: If you can update the firebase ones, I can merge the tags.

Comment: @BhargavRao - thank you for looking into this - sure, I can do that. Just a small question before I do it: can the [tag:firebase-admin] be renamed to [tag:firebase-admin-sdk] first (or after the change) while we are at it (it is its official name) or should I start a new meta Q&A to give it some time for dicussion?

Comment: It doesn't look like it needs to be changed. [firebase-admin] seems to be quite descriptive. Anyway, do feel free to open a new meta.

Comment: @BhargavRao - all done (at least those I know of). re:naming - thank you, I still think it should be renamed, but that is a question for another time as it is far from being an issue, I have to gather data on whether it makes sense or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went through all the posts that you mentioned, and it does look like merging [google-admin-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-admin-sdk) and [admin-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/admin-sdk) does make sense. After removing the posts that were related to [firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase), the tag now looks clean for a merge.

For now I have added [admin-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/admin-sdk) as synonym to [google-admin-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-admin-sdk). That is

[admin-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/admin-sdk) (× 56) → [google-admin-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-admin-sdk) (× 1187)

After a few days, I'll go ahead and merge the two tags, and then remove the synonym.

Comment: Yay - thank you! Let's hope there will be no more people who will slap Admin SDK to Firebase in the process (I will keep an eye on them until the merge happens as well).